# Is reflected sunlight the same quality as direct sunlight?

Tags: sunlight

I have a spot that receives small sunlight... I was wondering what devices can I use or how can I reflect sunlight from other locations... and if that would help.

For example, I saw that if you have a transparent tube filled with water, it would act as a "lamp" by capturing the sun rays at the top.

This is because I have some plants that seem to be affected by the lack of more sun light, and have light green / yellow leaves where normal is dark green.

Thanks!

Comment: They shouldn't be getting chlorosis from lack of light unless you've got them in a closet, covered with a tarp, or something. It's likely a different problem (whether or not they need extra light).

Answer (score 1):

A tube filled with water would heavily filter sunlight passing through it, as well as being heavy and awkward to arrange to hold in place. So that would NOT be "the same quality as direct sunlight," having most of the red end of the spectrum removed or greatly reduced.

Any mirror is imperfect (does not reflect 100% of light that strikes it, and won't reflect all parts of the spectrum equally) but most are close enough to work for plants.

It's naturally easiest or least fuss and expense to plant things suited to the level of light available in the spot.

If you want to make a fuss and spend money, a [heliostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliostat) would be the method to reflect sunlight onto the area, if you have a place where the heliostat could be located to get sunlight to reflect there.